# Geoserver CSS style for PropertyIsLike

Tags: geoserver, sld, filter, css, geoserver-css-module

I am trying to convert sld to css style. The below code is have written SLD style for filter a word using PropertyIsLike

```xml
  <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="%" singleChar="_" escape="\">
      <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>%police%</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

How to write the above SLD in CSS format?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/filters.html#filtering-on-data-attributes) it appears your query would be written as:

```
[name LIKE '%police%']
```

It doesn't appear that you can change the wildcard characters based on this:

> Patterns use _ to indicate a single unspecified character and % to
>   indicate an unknown number of unspecified characters.